# URL rewrites do not work after moving Magento installation to new server

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

After duplicating our web store onto a new server, copying the database over and changing the base url/safe base url in the db, all we get from the copied installation is the front page. That is, no custom url redirects work (for products, the admin panel, etc.), they all result in a 404 (and not the magento 404, the server default). Do you have any ideas what I could check out? Could there be an issue with one of the libraries included in magento?

I tried reindexing with /shell/indexer.php - which executed successfully but didn't fix the redirects.

Any ideas? Note I cannot access the admin panel via /admin because of this issue.

**Edit: solution was .htaccess file missing in root directory**
I added the sample htaccess file from the magento installation (I uploaded a copy in case someone finds it useful: http://sdrv.ms/13mw8Ok), and mod_rewrite was activated the next time I visited the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your vhosts file is setup correctly to allow mod_rewrite
2. Make sure your .htaccess file is setup correctly

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

You can access your admin through `/index.php/admin` in the meanwhile.

Comment: `/index.php/admin` was very helpful, thanks! Will check out mod_rewrite with our new web host if they can enable it.

Comment: the root .htaccess ended up being the problem. I added the sample .htaccess file from the magento installation which activated mod_rewrite among other things. Took me a while to find the sample .htaccess so I uploaded it here: http://sdrv.ms/13mw8Ok